# What does "so far, so good" mean

Tags: phrases

How can I translate the phrase:

> "so far, so good"

Example:

> So far, so good. Let’s see how the web server configures the web
>   application

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69509/does-so-far-so-good-carry-a-negative-connotation) (on ELU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it as "everything looks good, up to this point (in whatever we're doing or talking about)".

- The "so far" part means "up to this point".
- The "so good" part means "things look good (enough)"

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+far,+so+good):

> **so far, so good**
>   All is going well so far. *We are half finished with our project. So far, so good. The operation is proceeding quite nicely—so far, so good.*